# Extract Twitter status URL using Regex and convert to another string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract the Twitter status URL  from a text URL inside a post and use than use that URL to get the embed code from Twitter using their API. I have a problem with the URL extraction using JavaScript and Regex.

The Regex ignores URLs that are within single or double quotes so it won't render the code inside a hyperlink. I need to convert that URL to the embed HTML code I get from the Twitter API.

Javascript code (original Regex code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138483/twitter-status-url-regex) but modified to ignore text that starts with single or double quotes):

```
var str = '<p>https://twitter.com/oppomobileindia/status/798397636780953600</p>';
var matched = str.match(/^[^'"]*http(s)?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:#!\/)?(\w+)\/status(es)?\/(\d+)$/);

var url = matched[0];
```

`<p>` is just for an example of html text that can surround the URL, this can be any string, but if the URL is within quotation, it should be ignored.

I have two problems that I couldn't solve out.

1) In the matched[0], I get also the characters before the URL. How can I get only the URL?

2) How to replace the URL in the source string with another arbitrary text (Will eventually be the widget HTML code that I get from Twitter)?

Results expected:

1) var url should be: `"https://twitter.com/oppomobileindia/status/798397636780953600"`

2) var str should be: "`<p>this is a a arbitrary text that replaced the original url</p>"`  (or any other text in that matter)

Comment: show how should look the expected result to get a quick help

Comment: Well, to get the URL you might add a capturing group around the URL pattern, something like `var matched = str.match(/(^|[^'"])(https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:#!\/)?(\w+)\/status(?:es)?\/(\d+))/)[2];`. To replace just the URL, you just need to use backreference to restore the text inside the capturing group you need to keep, e.g. `str.replace(/(^|[^'"])(https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:#!\/)?(\w+)\/status(?:es)?\/(\d+))/, '$1NEW_CODE')`

Comment: @Idan Shechter, was the `@Wiktor's answer helpful for you?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'm testing it out now

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your code worked. Thanks a lot, please answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, it worked, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the URL value, you can add a [**capturing group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) around the URL pattern:

```
/(^|[^'"])(https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:#!\/)?(\w+)‌​\/status(?:es)?\/(\d‌​+))/
```

and access `[2]`, capturing group #2.

**Regex details**:

- `(^|[^'"])` - Capturing group #1: either start of string (`^`) or any char other than `"` and `'` (`[^'"]`)
- `(https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:#!\/)?(\w+)‌​\/status(?:es)?\/(\d‌​+))` - Capturing group 2:

  - `https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/` - a literal `https://twitter.com/` or  `http://twitter.com/` text
  - `(?:#!\/)?` - an optional (1 or 0 occurrence) sequence of `#!/`
  - `(\w+)‌` - Capturing group #3: one or more letters/digits or `_`
  - `​\/status(?:es)?\/` - literal `/status/` or `/statuses/` text
  - `(\d‌​+)` - Capturing group #4: one or more digits.

To replace just the URL, you just need to use capturing groups and [**backreferences**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) to restore the text inside the capturing groups you need to keep:

```
var replaced = str.replace(/(^|[^'"])(https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:#!\/)?(\w‌​+)\/status(?:es)?\/(‌​\d+))/, '$1NEW_CODE');
```

See JS demo:

```js
var str = '<p>https://twitter.com/oppomobileindia/status/798397636780953600</p>';
var matched = str.match(/(^|[^'"])(https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:#!\/)?(\w+)\/status(?:es)?\/(\d+))/);
var url = matched[2];
console.log(url);
var res = str.replace(/(^|[^'"])(https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:#!\/)?(\w+)\/status(?:es)?\/(\d+))/, '$1NEW_CODE');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Wiktor, just one additional thing if you don't mind. How can I replace the exact URL in that particular place. So if I have several URLs, I want to replace each one with its own unique widget code. I'm thinking about preserving the status id and replacing the string using that number, any idea how to modify the Regex to support it?

Comment: You have the ID captured into Group 4. In the replacement string, just use the appropriate backreference, `$4`.